# Reliably resolve location of a batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

A standard construct to get the directory of a batch file is to use `%~dp0`.

However, this returns the wrong directory if the batch file's name is in double quotes.

For example, npm generates cmd files in windows in the format

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\coffee-script\bin\coffee" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\coffee-script\bin\coffee" %*
)
```

When invoked without quotes the command succeeds as expected.

```
C:\test> coffee --version
CoffeeScript version 1.10.0
```

When invoked with quotes though, the command fails

```
C:\test> "coffee" --version
Error: 'C:\test\node_modules\coffee-script\bin\coffee'
```

What has happened is `%~dp0` has evaluated to the current working directory `C:\test\` instead of the directory the batch file is in.

Is there an alternative construct to `%~dp0` that is more reliable?

It is not uncommon for a build tool or other batch file to wrap an executable name in double quotes when issuing the command in case the name contains spaces.

Comment: Acquiesce and comply with this behaviour. Read answers and discussions to related questions (incomplete list!): [CMD: failure of %~d0 when CALL quotes the name of the batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19781569/3439404) and [In Batch file ~dp0 changes on changing directory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12141482/3439404) etc. etc.

Comment: Was this solved?